# How can I let my list return the list within a specific range

Tags: python, list, reference

So I'm trying to move every '1' in list `board` to the bottom list of lists. Here is what I mean,
If my input in this,

```
board = [[" "," ","1"," "],
         [" "," ","1"," "],
         ["1","1"," "," "],
         ["1"," "," ","1"]]
```

my output should return

```
[[" "," "," "," "],
 [" "," "," "," "],
 ["1"," ","1"," "],
 ["1","1","1","1"]]
```

If u do not understand, I basically have to move every '1' in the list to the lowest list in board in python.

Here is what I have so far,

```
board = [[" "," ","1"," "],
         [" "," ","1"," "],
         ["1","1"," "," "],
         ["1"," "," ","1"]]
def summ(board: [list[str]]):
    j = []
    for x in board:
        for i in x:
            j.append(i.count('1'))
    return sum(j)
def remove(board):
    r = []
    for x in board:
        for i in x:
            r.append(i.removesuffix('1'))
    return r
def new(board):
    s = list('1'* summ(board))
    return [remove(board) + s]
print(new(board))
```

and the output I get is this

```
[[' ', ' ', '', ' ', ' ', ' ', '', ' ', '', '', ' ', ' ', '', ' ', ' ', '', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]
```

What should I change??

Comment: `list(zip(*(sorted(column) for column in zip(*board))))`

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. just transpose array, sort it and transpose back again.

```
board = [[" "," ","1"," "],
         [" "," ","1"," "],
         ["1","1"," "," "],
         ["1"," "," ","1"]]
boardT=list((map(list, zip(*board))))
boardS=[sorted(L) for L in boardT]
boardR=list((map(list, zip(*boardS))))
print(boardR)

#ans=[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
     ['1', ' ', '1', ' '],
     ['1', '1', '1', '1']]
```